# Does git-svn renaming preserve SVN history?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-rewrite-history

I need to rename a file via Git while using git-svn. Will the history of the file in SVN be preserved after `dcommit`?

I know it will be if I'm using just Git or just SVN but I'm not sure if there is some history-preserving forwarding in between.

Currently cannot try it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as Git detects it as move or copy, in my experience it was also transported as move or copy to SVN, which means history was preserved.

Answer (score 0):

No!

I've renamed a large folder "Kundencenter" to "Kunden-Center".

In SVN I then had the old folder "Kundencenter" with loads of empty folders which also had the history and the new folder "Kunden-Center" which had no history.

I've used git version 2.35.1.windows.2.